# Why are the contents in `/var/lib/docker/btrfs` and `/var` different while their mount options are same (both are btrfs)

Tags: docker, btrfs

Please see the output below

```
$ mount
/dev/sda3 on /var type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/var)
/dev/sda3 on /var/lib/docker/btrfs type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/var)
```

This is the output of `ls`

```
$ ls /var
cache db lib local lock log mail opt run spool tmp

$ ls /var/lib/docker/btrfs
subvolumes
```

I am so confused. I thought the output of `ls /var/lib/docker/btrfs` is as same as `ls /var` because same block device is mounted to the both paths with same btrfs mount options (same subvolume).

Then I made my experiment like below

```
$ mkdir /tmp/var
$ mount /dev/sda3 /tmp/var -o subvolid=258
$ mount /dev/sda3 /tmp/var/lib/docker/btrfs -o subvolid=258

$ mount
/dev/sda3 on /tmp/var type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/var)
/dev/sda3 on /tmp/var/lib/docker/btrfs type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/var)

$ ls /tmp/var
cache db lib local lock log mail opt run spool tmp

$ ls /tmp/var/lib/docker/btrfs
cache db lib local lock log mail opt run spool tmp
```

`/tmp/var` and `/tmp/var/lib/docker/btrfs` are mounted by me, and their contents are same as expected.

I know the `/var/lib/docker/btrfs` is mounted by dockerd. What tricks does dockerd make making the contents in `/var/lib/docker/btrfs` and `/var` different while their btrfs mount options are same.

--

#### UPDATE

So there is no tricks made by dockerd. It is just a **bind mount**. Thank you  @AndyDalton.

Then I redid my experiment with "bind mount".

```
$ mkdir /tmp/var
$ mount /dev/sda3 /tmp/var -o subvolid=258
$ mount --bind /tmp/var/lib/docker/btrfs /tmp/var/lib/docker/btrfs  # bind-mount itself

$ mount
/dev/sda3 on /tmp/var type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/var)
/dev/sda3 on /tmp/var/lib/docker/btrfs type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/var)

$ ls /tmp/var
cache db lib local lock log mail opt run spool tmp

$ ls /tmp/var/lib/docker/btrfs
subvolumes
```

This time, the contents of `/tmp/var` and `/tmp/var/lib/docker/btrfs` are also different, just like `/var/` and `/var/lib/docker/btrfs`. Here is the printing of `findmnt`. It also indicates that it is just a **bind mount**.

```
$ findmnt /dev/sda3
TARGET                    SOURCE                               FSTYPE OPTIONS
/var                      /dev/sda3                            btrfs  rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/var
/var/lib/docker/btrfs     /dev/sda3[/var/lib/docker/btrfs]     btrfs  rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/var
/tmp/var                  /dev/sda3                            btrfs  rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/var
/tmp/var/lib/docker/btrfs /dev/sda3[/tmp/var/lib/docker/btrfs] btrfs  rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/var
```

The words below are from `mount` man page in section **Bind mount operation**

> Note that the filesystem mount options maintained by the kernel will remain the  same  as  those  on  the original  mount  point.

OK, so looks like **my original question is solved**.

Er..., wait, new question, the root question, without it I wouldn't have asked the original question in the first place -- Why does dockerd make such a bind mount? I saw such words in `mount` man page

> It's also possible to use a bind mount to  create a mountpoint from a regular directory, for example:
>
> ```
>         mount --bind foo foo
> ```

**What's the point of the command above -- turn a directory to a mountpoint by bind-mounting itself?**

I have posted [the follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607909/var-lib-docker-btrfs-is-a-bind-mount-of-itself-why-does-dockerd-make-such-a), please follow the link if you'd like to answer it.

--

#### UPDATE AGAIN

For [the follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607909/var-lib-docker-btrfs-is-a-bind-mount-of-itself-why-does-dockerd-make-such-a) "Why does dockerd make such a bind mount?", "What's the point to turn a directory to a mountpoint by bind-mounting itself?, I just copied my own answer I posted there to here, since that question is hidden (deleted).

> I might get to know what's the point to make directory a mountpoint. Some system operations/commands only works with mountpoint, rather than regular directory. I think this is why people turn a directory to a mountpoint -- for those operations/commands to work.

Comment: Looks like a bind mount.  Try running `findmnt` and look for things like `/var                                /dev/sda3[/somePathHere]`

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is a bind mount. Thank you so much. I am going to update my question to reflect the information.